# NestJs AggregateError, while starting the project

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, aggregateerror

I'm currently working on a backend project using Nest.js with TypeORM and a PostgreSQL database. Everything was running smoothly until I encountered the following error during the startup of my application:

```
[10:23:44 AM] Starting compilation in watch mode...

[10:23:49 AM] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[info] [NestFactory] [9/6/2023, 10:23:51 AM] => Starting Nest application... (+0ms)
[info] [InstanceLoader] [9/6/2023, 10:23:51 AM] => PassportModule dependencies initialized (+40ms)
[info] [InstanceLoader] [9/6/2023, 10:23:51 AM] => TypeOrmModule dependencies initialized (+0ms)
[info] [InstanceLoader] [9/6/2023, 10:23:51 AM] => AppModule dependencies initialized (+0ms)
AggregateError: 
    at internalConnectMultiple (node:net:1114:18)
    at afterConnectMultiple (node:net:1667:5)
```

I didn't make any recent code changes, and I've already tried restarting my application and double-checking my database credentials, but the error persists. Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this AggregateError and how to resolve it?

Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

**What I Tried:**

1. **Restarting the Application:** Initially, I attempted to resolve the issue by simply restarting my Nest.js application to see if the error would disappear.
2. **Double-Checking Database Credentials:** Since the error message mentioned a network-related issue (**`node:net`**), I carefully reviewed and confirmed that my PostgreSQL database credentials (such as the host, port, username, and password) were correctly configured in my TypeORM configuration file.
3. **Reviewing Recent Code Changes:** I thoroughly inspected my codebase for any recent changes that might have introduced this error. However, I didn't find any recent code modifications that appeared to be directly related to this issue.

**What I Was Expecting:**

I was expecting that after performing these steps, the application would start successfully without any errors, as it had been running smoothly before. However, despite my efforts, the AggregateError persisted, and I'm currently seeking assistance to understand the root cause of this error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was `undefined` that appeared in the values of the connection options.

Here's an example of my setup (it was one of the connections):

```
export const getDS = () => {
  const options: PostgresConnectionOptions = {
    name: 'secondConnection',
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.ANOTHER_DB_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.ANOTHER_DB_PORT ?? "5432"),
    database: process.env.ANOTHER_DB_NAME,
    username: process.env.ANOTHER_DB_USER,
    logging: process.env.DB_LOG === "1",
    password: process.env.ANOTHER_DB_PASSWORD,
    entities: anotherEntityList,
    applicationName: "redacted",
    migrationsRun: false,
  }

  console.log(options) //<- log here to check they are filled correctly
  
  return { options, ds: new DataSource(options) }
}
```

I forgot to include all the necessary environment variables after deployment so  the error constantly showed up in the logs.

Comment: This resolved the same error for me, but in a different context: nodejs + docker + mondob cloud atlas.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, and managed to solve it. The issue was that i'm using redis as a socket.io adapter, and my redis server was not running. After starting the redis server it works again.

This error was more descriptive in the past...

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem too.

Turned out I hardcoded `type` in the TypeORMConnection options object to 'mysql'.

Changing it to `postgres` resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

Read if you're running a dockerized Postgres SQL !!!

For me the problem was due to a lot of postgres volumes in docker , i went in docker desktop and deleted all volumes that are not used .